# How can I make both of these UICollectionViews appear in the same View?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have two `UICollectionViews` that I need in one View.

They have two different `CollectionViewCell` classes. The first `CollectionView` cell class is `ConfirmOffersCollectionViewCell` and the second is `ConfirmRequestsCollectionViewCell`.

I am able to have both `CollectionViews` appear and function if I set both cells to the same class, but they display the same images. I need them to be populated by two separate image arrays.

The only thing I know to do is to copy and paste my `func collectionView()` code and change the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` and `numberOfItemsInSection` properties. But I am unable to run the same function twice.

Here is the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView1: UICollectionView!

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView2: UICollectionView!




func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return images1.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: ConfirmOffersCollectionViewCell = collectionView1.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ConfirmOffersCollectionViewCell
    images1[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            cell.image.image = image
        }
    }
    return cell
}




func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return images2.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: ConfirmRequestsCollectionViewCell = collectionView2.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ConfirmRequestsCollectionViewCell
    images2[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            cell.image.image = image
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: You can try to use if condition against collectionView variable in delegate methods. For example, if collectionView == collectionView1 return images1.count else return images2.count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use same functions inside a single class. Instead you will need to identify each collection view somehow (by creating outlets or giving them a tag) and then in each function check the `collectionview` parameter and compare it with your collection views. Example :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if collectionView = secondCollectionView{
       return images2.count
    }else{
       return images1.count
    }
```

}

Also you will need to check similarly at `cellForRowAtIndexPath`as well